# Windows shortcut to a symbolic link to an executable

Tags: java, windows, symlink, shortcut-file

I'm going to use an issue I'm having with a Java application to explain my question by way of an example, but this question has nothing really to do with Java.

I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit) and I want to create a Start Menu shortcut to execute a GUI Java application. As of Java 8, the installer puts NTFS symbolic links in a well-known place pointing to a release-specific (i.e. subject to frequent change) directory:

```
C:\>where javaw
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

C:\>dir C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D4DC-33AF

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

05/03/2015  15:40    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\javaw.exe]
```

I created a shortcut whose target command line was C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe *java_app.jar* but when I run it, Windows says the javaw.exe path does not exist. I can successfully run the same command line from the Windows Run dialog; just not from a shortcut. Can anyone offer a solution? (I prefer not to create a batch file to run the command, as that would create a useless console box.)

(NB You can also see the same issue without using Java. Just create a symbolic link to Notepad.exe (using the MKLINK command) and then try to create a shortcut to the symbolic link.)

Comment: Just shortcuts? Double clicking directly has never worked for me either, at least not in Vista or Windows 7. It's something wacky with how the `ShellExecute` API is invoked by Explorer, et al. As a workaround you could create a non-console launcher that calls `CreateProcess` and exits.

Comment: Thanks, eryksun, that's a good point about double-clicking having this problem too. Strangely enough, running the same symlink from the Windows Run box works ok, even though it's also Explorer that runs that too. Your suggestion for writing a launcher is probably the best solution.

Comment: Has this been resolved?  I had the exact same problem last year, and I do not have it today.  I do not know exactly what changed, how I fixed it, or if it was a specific Windows Update that fixed it.  But I am able to use a shortcut target of `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe -Xmx1G -jar "C:\Program Files\MyApp\myapp.jar".  I created the shortcut on the desktop, then pinned to task bar.  After every update, the symlink gets fiddled by the Java installer, and I have to manually re-create the shortcut.  It can't be updated because the path has not changed, yet won't work otherwise.

Comment: @user314159: the problem has always been intermittent - a shortcut to a symlink would work sometimes but not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do the useless batch file. Use [CALL](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true) inside of it so the console window closes immediately after starting your application.

Also, not on Windows machine right now, but can you create a shortcut to `CMD.exe` instead and pass your command in there? You may do it in conjunction with `CALL` in case console window appears.

Comment: Thanks dimoniy. I think you mean START (CALL is for calling batch files). The command line "cmd /c start javaw ...", with the shortcut configured to start it in a minimized window, is a reasonable compromise, though it's a shame it has to create a window at all.

Answer (score 0):

This simple launcher may be useful; you can create one or more shortcuts to it with the same command line parameters you would have used in the shortcut to javaw.exe.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void NoCRTMain(void)
{
    wchar_t * cmdline = GetCommandLineW();
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    if (!CreateProcess(L"C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\javaw.exe", cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to launch Java.", L"runjava.exe", MB_OK);
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

To compile in Visual Studio, you will need to change some project settings:

- Buffer Security Check to No in C/C++ Code Generation
- Ignore All Default Libraries to Yes in Linker Input
- Entry Point to NoCRTMain in Linker Advanced
- /DYNAMICBASE:NO and /FIXED:YES [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30659232/886887)

(Or you can change the main function from NoCRTMain to WinMain, but then you need to install the C runtime or link it statically.)

Obviously you could easily modify the code to run symbolic links other than javaw.exe, although some programs might not like the fact that `argv[0]` doesn't point to the application's own executable.