# Why do my CRT-free applications intermittently crash on startup?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

For example, this application:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>

int __stdcall NoCRTMain(void) 
{
    int result;

    PWSTR lpCmdLine = GetCommandLine();

    for (;;)
    {
        if (*lpCmdLine == L'"') 
        {
            lpCmdLine++;
            for (;;)
            {
                if (*lpCmdLine == L'"') break;
                if (*lpCmdLine == L'\0') break;
                lpCmdLine++;
            }
        }
        if (*lpCmdLine == L' ') break;
        if (*lpCmdLine == L'\0') break;
        lpCmdLine++;
    }

    while (*lpCmdLine == ' ') lpCmdLine++;

    result = MessageBox(NULL, lpCmdLine, L"Scripting Engine", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);

    if (result != IDOK) for (;;) Sleep(INFINITE);

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Built in Visual Studio 2010 as a 64-bit application with no C runtime, this works perfectly - most of the time.  Sometimes it will start crashing on startup for no readily apparent reason.  This crash occurs before any of the code in the application is run (see below).

When the problem occurs, it occurs only for a particular instance of the executable, i.e., a particular executable file.  An byte-by-byte identical copy of the file will run normally.  The problem may (will?) disappear when the computer is rebooted.  I am running tests to try to reliably reproduce the issue, so that I can identify the circumstances under which the problem can occur, e.g., only if Visual Studio is installed?  Only if anti-virus is installed?  But so far I haven't had much success in reproducing the problem by any procedure other than dumb luck.

Most of the time, debugging shows that kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk is calling an invalid address instead of the the address of NoCRTMain, although some recent runs have failed earlier than that, apparently while loading DLLs.

I believe I have tracked the issue down to ImageBase being set incorrectly when the module is loaded.  On a working instance, a memory dump at 0x00D8 relative to the executable module, structure _IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 from winnt.h:

```
00000001`3f5900d8 0b 02 0a 00 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000001`3f5900e8 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 59 3f 01 00 00 00
```

shows that ImageBase (the last eight bytes) contains the address of the start of the module, in this case 1`3f590000.  On a failing instance, the same memory dump

```
00000001`3fc600d8 0b 02 0a 00 00 02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000001`3fc600e8 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 8f 3f 01 00 00 00
```

shows that ImageBase, rather than being 1`3fc60000 as expected, is 1`3f8f0000.

This seems to occurs before the earliest point at which a debugger can examine the process, so I'm not sure how to proceed.  Perhaps I need to do kernel debugging?  I currently have a VMWare vSphere virtual machine exhibiting the problem, and I've got a snapshot I can revert to, so I can afford to experiment.

So:

- does anyone know the cause of this behaviour, and more importantly, how to prevent it?
- is my interpretation of the memory dump mistaken?
- any debugging/troubleshooting suggestions?

Compiler options:

```
/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS"
/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS- /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t
/Zc:forScope /Fp"x64\Release\sehalt.pch" /Fa"x64\Release\" /Fo"x64\Release\"
/Fd"x64\Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /errorReport:queue
```

Linker options:

```
/OUT:"C:\documents\code\w7lab-scripting\sehalt\x64\Release\sehalt.exe"
/INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib"
"winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib"
"oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB
/MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\sehalt.exe.intermediate.manifest"
/ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG
/PDB:"C:\documents\code\w7lab-scripting\sehalt\x64\Release\sehalt.pdb"
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF 
/PGD:"C:\documents\code\w7lab-scripting\sehalt\x64\Release\sehalt.pgd"
/LTCG /TLBID:1 /ENTRY:"NoCRTMain" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT
/MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

PS: looking at which of my applications are known to have failed in this way and which aren't, I suspect that the problem only occurs for executables that are less than one page (4096 bytes) in size.

Comment: Re: _"An byte-by-byte identical copy of the file will run normally. The problem may (will?) disappear when the computer is rebooted."_ suggests to me that the problem doesn't lie strictly within your source code, but perhaps with the linking / loader process. Could be that some info is missing in the executable, leading the OS's loader having to "guess" some parameter (sometimes incorrectly) and caching that guess.

Comment: How do you compile and link your code? Could you add the relevant settings / command line to your question?

Comment: @stakx: thanks; I've added the compiler and linker command lines.

Comment: This has ASLR written all over it, omit the /DYNAMICBASE linker option.  Underlying issue is probably a relocation problem, hard to see.

Comment: @Hans: a good point, but I'm thinking it doesn't solve the problem; even if I request that the application not be relocated, the system administrator can override that via EMET, and in fact is encouraged to do so.  (Unfortunately I'm still having no luck reproducing the issue for testing purposes, so I can't confirm whether turning ASLR off actually helps or not.)

Comment: Nonetheless, it should be good enough for my purposes.  I'll try it out, at any rate, and see what happens.

Comment: EMET can't relocate an executable without relocations. If you don't use the /DYNAMICBASE or /FIXED:NO options, your executable won't have relocations.

Comment: @RossRidge: right you are.  I had thought the "mandatory ASLR" setting meant, well, mandatory: if it couldn't perform the relocation, it wouldn't let the executable run.  But I just tried it, and you're right - if the executable can't be relocated, it runs anyway, at the preferred address.  Thanks.

Comment: If it worked that way then it would be preventing a heck of lot of programs from running. Mandatory ASLR still has an effect though, it forces DLLs to be loaded at different addresses even if they didn't use  /DYNAMICBASE. The /FIXED:NO option has always been the default for DLLs so most of them have relocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A year on, I'm finally confident in claiming that Hans' suggestion has worked perfectly: if the application is built with the `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` and `/FIXED:YES` options, the problem does not occur.